# Extracting tabular form data from multiple webpages into an excel using VBA macros..!

Tags: vba, excel

Extracting tabular form data from multiple webpages into an excel using VBA macros..!! Currently iam using below link but i could able to only one webpage in the code..i have list of ulr's to get data from...and it has to come in vertical..!! please suggest me.. :)

```
Sub INDEXdata()

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://recorder.maricopa.gov/recdocdata/GetRecDataDetail.aspx?rec=19770000007" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "rec=19770000006"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "2,3"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: OK.  Is this one macro working for you?  What is happening when you attempt to use different URLs?

Comment: Please provide more infos about what your actual problem is.

Comment: iam unable to give multiple url's at a time... if i want to extract data for another url every time i need to change the url in the code...so i want loop to be happen there..

Comment: i could able to use different URL's as well but the thing is i need to run for multiple URL's at a time @Ann L.

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't know how much programming background you have, and I also don't know what parts of the code you posted are specific to that one source url and target location.

But, something like this might work.  I made the assumption that the url, the destination, and the name would change for each page you wanted to pull from.

What I did was take the part of the code that looked like it would be true for all of the source pages and destinations, and put that in its own parameterized subroutine.  The original routine `IndexData` just specifies the URL and the destination, and the name, for each copy operation.

```
 Sub IndexData()
     GetData("http://recorder.maricopa.gov/recdocdata/GetRecDataDetail.aspx?rec=19770000007" , _
             "$A$1", _
             "rec=19770000006")
     GetData("http://somewhereelse.com/somedata.aspx?rec=12345", _
              "$A$2", _
              "rec=12345")
     GetData("http://anotherurl.com/etc", _
              "$A$3", _
              "something")
 End

 Sub  GetData(url as string, destination as string, name as string)
   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
      "URL;" & url , Destination:=Range(destination))
      .Name = name
      .FieldNames = True
      .RowNumbers = False
      .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
      .PreserveFormatting = True
      .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
      .BackgroundQuery = True
      .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
      .SavePassword = False
      .SaveData = True
      .AdjustColumnWidth = True
       .RefreshPeriod = 0
      .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
      .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
      .WebTables = "2,3"
      .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
      .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
      .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
      .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
      .WebDisableRedirections = False
      .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is happening that shouldn't, or not happening that should?

Comment: Perhaps the code I put has a syntax error.  (I just copied and adapted yours.)  Do you see any errors in the error list?